# Unit testing Kotlin Flows and toList()

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have this Unit test:

```
@Test
    fun `should emit user repos on success`() = rule.dispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // GIVEN
        val repo = Repo(name = "someRepo1", owner = RepoOwner(TEST_USERNAME), stars = 55)
        val channel = Channel<Repo>()
        val flow = channel.consumeAsFlow()

        doReturn(flow)
            .whenever(repository)
            .getUserRepos(TEST_USERNAME)

        // WHEN
        launch {
            channel.send(repo)
        }

        userDetailViewModel.lookupUserRepos(TEST_USERNAME)

        // THEN
        verify(userReposObserver).onChanged(listOf(repo))
    }
```

which tests this code in the view model:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun lookupUserRepos(login: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            val flow = userRepository.getUserRepos(login)
            _userRepos.value = flow
                .catch { _isUserReposError.value = true }
                .toList()
        }
    }
```

Debugging shows that the flow does get the `repo` but something about `toList()` breaks the test (I get test failure `Wanted but not invoked observer.onChanged...no interactions with this mock`

Non-test works but test using `toList()` breaks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you `@Mock` the userReposObserver? as you are using _verify_ , you need to `@Mock` it first...

Comment: `viewModelScope.launch` at this line you'll need to inject `dispatcher` then in the test you can put the test coroutine dispatcher so that you can test it properly.